# What's the Standard Way of Loading Views in a NavigationView where each Owns a Model that's Populated from an API?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have 2 views: A & B. View A has a model that loads its data from an API endpoint, and the same for view B.

View A has a button, that once clicked pushes view B on the stack. Here's code that does this:

**App:**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TempApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ViewA()
        }
    }
}
```

**View/Model A:**

```
import SwiftUI

let REQUEST_DELAY = 6.0 // to simulate(ish) a network request

struct ViewA: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ViewAModel = ViewAModel()
    @State var shouldGoToNextView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if (self.model.isLoaded) {
                VStack {
                    Text(self.model.data)
                        .font(.title)
                    NavigationLink(destination: ViewB(), isActive:$shouldGoToNextView) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    Button(action: {self.shouldGoToNextView=true}) {
                        Text("GO")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text("Not ready...")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.shouldGoToNextView = false
        })
    }
}

class ViewAModel : ObservableObject {
    var data: String = ""
    @Published var isLoaded : Bool = false
    
    init() {
        // simulate getting the data from the network
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + REQUEST_DELAY) {
            // your code here
            self.data = "All loaded fine.."
            self.isLoaded = true
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewA()
    }
}
```

**Model/View B:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewB: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ViewBModel = ViewBModel()
    var body: some View {
        if (self.model.isLoaded) {
            Text(self.model.data)
                .font(.title)
        } else {
            Text("Secondary data not ready...")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

class ViewBModel: ObservableObject {
    var data: String = ""
    @Published var isLoaded: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        // simulate getting the data from the network
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + REQUEST_DELAY) {
            self.data = "Secondary model data loaded fine.."
            self.isLoaded = true
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewB()
    }
}
```

This code works when run but I have 1 question and 1 issue:

**Question:** Is this the best way to achieve the above in SwiftUI? Specifically, I'm not sure about my use of State/ObservedObject and the combination of a NavigationLink and a Button to navigate to another view.

**Issue:** I cannot preview View A in the real app I'm working on because View A's code instantiates View B straight away (in the NavigationLink call) so Model B makes a network call to load its data, and that results in an error:

> Updating took more than 5 seconds

The sample app above previews fine even though I put a delay on loading the data so I'm not sure why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- To go to view B, its far easier with this code:

```
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
            Text("Your buttons text")
        }
```

2- Instead of using `ObservedObject` you should be using `StateObject`.

3- Instad of using a `isLoaded`, you just can @Published your `data`.

4- To be able to preview those I suggest you to wrap them inside a container view where you can pass its dependency, in this case `data` which is a String. For example:

```
struct A: View {
   var viewModel = ViewModel()
   var body: some View {
        if !data.isEmpty {
          ABodyView(data: data)
        }
    }

 }

struct ABodyView: View {
     let data: String 
      var body: some View {
         Text(data)
      }
}

struct ABodyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let previews: some View {
        ABodyView(data: "whatever you want")
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips! I'm not sure I 100% understand the previews tip, but I'll try to do it later today and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Actually changing the models to `StateObject` instead of `ObservedObject` as you suggest has fixed the preview issue I was having! Thanks again.